# Pass Multidimensional Array in Query String to Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, query-string

When passing a multidimensional array to a rails controller, it does not seem to parse correctly.  Am I doing it wrong?

```
url: http://localhost:3000/people?sort[][]=lastname&sort[][]=1&sort[][]=firstname&sort[][]=1
params: {
          "sort" => [
        [0] nil,
        [1] nil,
        [2] nil,
        [3] nil
    ],
        "action" => "index",
    "controller" => "people"
}
```

should be:

```
params: {
          "sort" => [
        [0] => [
          [0] => 'lastname',
          [1] => 1
        ],
        [1] = > [
          [0] => 'firstname',
          [1] => 1
        ]
    ],
        "action" => "index",
    "controller" => "people"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays in the query string.

It supports one-dimensional arrays:

```
http://localhost:3000/people?sort[]=lastname&sort[]=firstname
# params[:sort] == ['lastname', 'firstname']
```

and also supports hashes:

```
http://localhost:3000/people?sort[lastname]=asc&sort[firstname]=desc
# params[:sort] == {:lastname => 'asc', :firstname => 'desc'}
```

Comment: This seems to be supported in Rails 4, but not anymore in Rails 5.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930886/rails-5-get-request-nested-array-parameter-changes-unexpectedly