# Rails 5 GET request nested array parameter changes unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rack

I have upgraded a Rails 4 application to Rails 5 (5.2.4.1 to be exact).

I have a GET endpoint in my code with an rspec test.

The test code sends the request as:

```
get :fetch, params: { id: 123, logs: [[1, 2, :weekly], [1, 4, :mothly]] }
```

When the controller receives the request, `params['logs']` contains

```
[["1"], ["2"], ["weekly"], ["1"], ["4"], ["monthly"]]
```

This is different from what I expected, which is

```
[["1", "2", "weekly"], ["1", "4", "monthly"]]
```

The incoming URL contains (after decoding the URL): `?id=123&logs[][]=1&logs[][]=2&logs[][]=weekly&logs[][]=1&logs[][]=4&logs[][]=monthly`

This is the same URL in Rails 4, but it worked somehow.  Was something else being passed?
In any case, it's no longer working Rails 5.
The Rails doc https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters does not mention nested array parameters.

Is it possible to make this work with Rails 5?  Is there any quick workaround?

The problem could be with `rack` gem.  The two versions used are: 1.6.13 and 2.2.2.

(I can send the whole structure as a json string in one parameter; I know this is an alternative solution. So please don't propose this as a solution.)

Thank you.

Comment: For this kind of params, I usually use `post`. I know that `post` is only for `posting` or `creating` data, but it can handle a bigger request param because your `logs` can get bigger with time.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23066966/9273735